# "ServiceLocationProvider must be set" in .net core DI servicecollection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-core, dependency-injection

I am migrating from MVVMLight dependency injection SimpleIoc to ServiceCollection from Microsoft.Extensions.Dependency dll in my WPF application.

In this

I am trying to replace this line
ServicesLocator.SetLocatorProvider(()=> SimpleIoc.Default).

In my page

IServiceCollection Service=new ServiceCollection();

I want to get instance with unique key like below:

ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance(Guid.NewGuid.Tostring()). This is working in SimpleIoc but after migration not working.

I trid multiple ways like

ServicesLocator.SetLocatorProvider(Service().BuildServiceProvider())

To get instance, Without Key(Guid) we have the method but couldn't find with key.

Any help?

Comment: Can you please write a concrete example with a bit more detail and propper formatting. F.e. `ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance(Guid.NewGuid.Tostring())` is not working because of spelling issues in `Guid.NewGuid() ` and  `.ToString()`.

Comment: Are you trying to resolve a unique instance of a type or what is your issue? How do you register the type then? And how and where do you set up the container?

Comment: Yes I tried to get unique instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have fixed the issue.

I used **Microsoft.Extensions.Dependencyainjection** dll.

To get unique instance earlier we used

```
ServiceLocator.Current.
    GetInstance<IService>(Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
```

To repalce this I have used like below:

```
IServiceCollection _service=new ServiceCollection();
_service.addscoped<IService, Service>();

Ioc.Default.ConfigureService(_service.BuildServiceProvider());
```

In particular page I did like below to get unique instance:

```
Ioc.Default.CreateScope().ServiceProvider.GetService<IService>();
```

Comment: Note that you can always mark your own answer as accepted one (checkmark on the left).